# After fixing a validation error in Apex 19.2 a page submit is no longer possible

Tags: oracle-apex

So I have a form in Apex 19.2 and I am using the build in validation function of APEX.

If we have a case where someone doesnt fill the field and presses the submit button, the page will notify the user that an validation error has occured. 
However after fixing that said error you can no longer submit the page since APEX is throwing an errror saying a page with this PID has already been submited. Also the data from the attempted form doesnt appear in the Database.
The only solution at this point is to reload the page and refill it starting from zero.

Comment: I have never seen this behaviour in my own applications. Can you set up a demo application on https://apex.oracle.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Page Designer, open up **page Level** attribute, go to group **Advance** and change the attribute **Enable duplicate page submissions** to **Yes - enable page to be re-posted**.

If you install APEX 20.1, this bug has been fixed.